# Is this question ok for this site

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I see that many users say that many games (in this case I looked at 2D games)  have inappropriate controls. I also noticed that when trying to create my own games that there is no "natural" control/steering like a Joystick was historically and no intuitive keyboard like the PC has had WASD to control many games (or the arrow keys). I see that several games have buttons with arrows and I also myself placed button at the bottom of the view for my game scenario.

[image]

Is there a more natural/standard/intuitive/"preferred" way to achive this kind of 2D control?

Answer (score 6):

**Game development (and other development-related things) are off-topic on Android Enthusiasts.** This community is mainly for solving problems *as Android end-users*.

Instead, there is a sister site for this specific topic, [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com). Otherwise, since this might also affect user-experience, [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21540) is also a possible alternative.